# How to fix VS Code showing blurry shadows after scrolling or switching between files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is a screenshot from my VS Code:

[image: this is screenshot from my vs code]

Maybe I installed some extension that caused this effect, but after uninstalling my recently installed extensions, it still looks like this. I tried to reset my user settings but it still looks like this.

Comment: it is not the regular look but you can try to disable **graphics acceleration**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you've tried to install the "Vibrancy" extension.
This extension changes the default CSS of Visual Studio Code and I think the latest version of Visual Studio Code is not letting us change its default CSS. I also have restarted my laptop because I am facing the same problem I think reinstalling Visual Studio Code is the best option, or we will have to wait for the developers of Visual Studio Code to fix this bug.

Comment: yes my last extension install is "vibrancy"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I uninstalled the "Vibrancy" extension, then restarted my PC.

I then opened another project and it's working as it was working before.